# Как сделать представленную структуру

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Мой мозг выдал фатальную ошибку, когда попытался разобраться...
Как поставить это изображение справа от текста?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* Настройки шрифта */
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #81858e;
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* Container
================== */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
  /* Выравнивание элемента по центру */
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header
================== */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 35px 0;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__inner nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Navigation
================== */

.nav {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
}

.nav__link {
  color: #bab8b8;
  margin-left: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .2s linear;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  color: #3984f3;
}

.nav__sign-in {
  color: #3984f3;
  margin-left: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid #3984f3;
  padding: 13px 16px;
}


/* Introduction
================== */

.intro {
  display: flex;
  /* вертикально по центру */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.intro__inner {
  width: 100%;
}

.intro__desc {
  padding-top: 330px;
}

.intro__title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 75px;
  color: #091e40;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.intro__subtitle {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #81858e;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}


/* Button
================== */

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 20px 45px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3984f3;
  transition: color .3s linear;
  outline: none
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3271cf;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__inner">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Image"></a>

        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Video</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Destinations</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Booking</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__sign-in">Sing In</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Introduction -->
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro__inner">
        <div class="intro__desc">
          <h1 class="intro__title">Travel around <br /> the world</h1>
          <h2 class="intro__subtitle">Plan and book your perfect trip with expert advice,<br /> travel tips, destination information and<br /> inspiration from us.</h2>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="btn btn--blue">Sign Up Now</a>
        <img src="img/intro-img.png" alt="" class="intro__image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Я бы это изображение сделал фоном

Answer (score 1):

Способов миллион. В данном случае я решил добавить обертку для флекса (класс flex-wrapper) и обертку для картинки (класс wrapper), так как флекс нормально только с блочными элементами работает по сути, а img не display:block по умолчанию.

```css
<style>
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* Настройки шрифта */
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #81858e;
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* Container
================== */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
  /* Выравнивание элемента по центру */
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header
================== */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 35px 0;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__inner nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Navigation
================== */

.nav {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
}

.nav__link {
  color: #bab8b8;
  margin-left: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .2s linear;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  color: #3984f3;
}

.nav__sign-in {
  color: #3984f3;
  margin-left: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid #3984f3;
  padding: 13px 16px;
}


/* Introduction
================== */

.intro {
  display: flex;
  /* вертикально по центру */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.intro__inner {
  width: 100%;
}

.intro__desc {
  padding-top: 330px;
}

.intro__title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 75px;
  color: #091e40;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.intro__subtitle {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #81858e;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}


/* Button
================== */

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 20px 45px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3984f3;
  transition: color .3s linear;
  outline: none
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3271cf;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.flex-wrapper {
    display: flex;  /*применим flex */
    justify-content: space-between; /* скажим что бы элементы обертки распологались по противоположным краям друг от друга */
    align-items: center; /*выровняем элементы обертки по центру (в данном случае относительно вертикали) */
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__inner">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Image"></a>

        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Video</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Destinations</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Booking</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__sign-in">Sing In</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Introduction -->
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro__inner">

        <div class="flex-wrapper">

            <div class="intro__desc">
              <h1 class="intro__title">Travel around <br /> the world</h1>
              <h2 class="intro__subtitle">Plan and book your perfect trip with expert advice,<br /> travel tips, destination information and<br /> inspiration from us.</h2>
              <a href="" class="btn btn--blue">Sign Up Now</a>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapper-block">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/kJN5S8B/Desktop-200802-1252.jpg" alt="" class="intro__image">
            </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header {
 background: url("../img/img.png") no-repeat right bottom / cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно загрузить заранее большую картинку и поставить её фоном, используя `position: absolute`

```js
const root = document.querySelector(':root');
const header = document.querySelector('header');
const headerImg = document.querySelector('header img');
headerImg.addEventListener('load', mainCode);

function mainCode() {
  function calcHeightHeader() {
    const heightHeader = header.scrollHeight;
    const heightWindow = window.innerHeight;
    root.style.setProperty('--heightHeader', heightHeader + 'px');
    root.style.setProperty('--myvh', heightWindow / 100 + 'px');
  }

  calcHeightHeader();

  window.addEventListener('resize', calcHeightHeader);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --grey: #bab8b8;
  --blue: #3984f3;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.btn {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  color: var(--blue);
  border: 2px solid var(--blue);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
}

.btn.hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--blue);
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--blue);
}

.btn.hover:hover {
  color: var(--blue);
  background-color: white;
}

.link {
  color: var(--grey);
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.link:hover {
  color: var(--blue);
}

header {
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--grey);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.header__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header__img span {
  color: var(--blue);
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

.header__img img {
  min-width: 50px;
}

.header__img>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header__nav>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.intro {
  min-height: calc(var(--myvh)*100 - var(--heightHeader));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.intro__container > h1, .intro__container > p {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.intro h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.intro h1 span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
}

.intro__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__container">
      <div class="header__img">
        <div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">
        </div>
        <span>Rhea</span>
      </div>
      <nav class="header__nav">
        <a class="link" href="">Home</a>
        <a class="link" href="">Video</a>
        <a class="link" href="">Destinations</a>
        <a class="link" href="">Booking</a>
        <a class="btn" href="">Sign In</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro__container">
      <h1>
        <span>Travel around</span>
        <span>the world</span>
      </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et sequi accusantium voluptas asperiores necessitatibus perferendis cumque vel!
      </p>
      <a class="btn hover" href="">Sign Up Now</a>
      <img class="intro__bg" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/1000" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или так

```js
const root = document.querySelector(':root');
const header = document.querySelector('header');
const headerImg = document.querySelector('header img');
headerImg.addEventListener('load', mainCode);

function mainCode() {
  function calcHeightHeader() {
    const heightHeader = header.scrollHeight;
    const heightWindow = window.innerHeight;
    root.style.setProperty('--heightHeader', heightHeader + 'px');
    root.style.setProperty('--myvh', heightWindow / 100 + 'px');
  }

  calcHeightHeader();

  window.addEventListener('resize', calcHeightHeader);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --grey: #bab8b8;
  --blue: #3984f3;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.btn {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  color: var(--blue);
  border: 2px solid var(--blue);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
}

.btn.hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--blue);
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--blue);
}

.btn.hover:hover {
  color: var(--blue);
  background-color: white;
}

.link {
  color: var(--grey);
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.link:hover {
  color: var(--blue);
}

header {
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--grey);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.header__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header__img span {
  color: var(--blue);
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

.header__img img {
  min-width: 50px;
}

.header__img>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header__nav>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.intro {
  min-height: calc(var(--myvh)*100 - var(--heightHeader));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.intro__container-left>h1,
.intro__container-left>p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.intro h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.intro h1 span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
}

.intro__container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.intro__container > * {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__container">
      <div class="header__img">
        <div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">
        </div>
        <span>Rhea</span>
      </div>
      <nav class="header__nav">
        <a class="link" href="">Home</a>
        <a class="link" href="">Video</a>
        <a class="link" href="">Destinations</a>
        <a class="link" href="">Booking</a>
        <a class="btn" href="">Sign In</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro__container">
      <div class="intro__container-left">
        <h1>
          <span>Travel around</span>
          <span>the world</span>
        </h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et sequi accusantium voluptas asperiores necessitatibus perferendis cumque vel!
        </p>
        <a class="btn hover" href="">Sign Up Now</a>

      </div>
      <div class="intro__container-right">
        <img class="intro__img" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/1000" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но я бы выбрал первый вариант, потому что `absolute` блоку можно легко заменить размеры, а также позицию

Comment: Тут можно обойтись и без JS, захламив чуть вёрстку, но смысл такой же будет